# jQuery selectors -> all TD within a specific table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still learning jQuery and the selector bit is incredibly useful, but I still don't understand it perfectly well.

**I have a table with id=table1, and I want to select all td's in this table.**
(really I want to wrap the text within each td with a div with overflow:hidden so I can force the cell heights to be uniform.)

**What's the appropriate syntax for the jQuery** (javaScript?) **selector?**

Any links to awesome selector tutorials are also welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should do the trick

```
$('#table1 td').wrapInner('<div class="no-overflow"></div>');
```

and add a css rule in your stylesheet

```
.no-overflow{
      overflow:hidden;
      /*and whatever other css properties here*/
 }
```

For completeness here is the documentation about

- [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)
- [all selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- the [Descendant Selector *jQuery('ancestor descendant')*](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) that we used in this situation

Comment: I think you want $('#table1 td').wrapInner('<div style="overflow: hidden;">');  jQuery automatically adds in the </div>

Comment: @Surreal, best to be standard compliant though :) .. so you could use a self closing div `'<div style="overflow: hidden;" />'`

Answer (score 3):

This will select all the cells:

```
$("#table1 td")
```

jQuery uses CSS3 selectors, read about them here:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#table1").find("td");
```

Comment: No need for .find(), one selector will do: $("#table1 td")

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#table1 td").each(function() {
  var text = $(this).html();
  var div = $("<div class=hiddenOverflow></div>");
  div.html(text);
  $(this).html(div);
});
```

Comment: There's actually a jQuery method that does this: http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/